# How to make sure, that backend call will be executed

Tags: android

I'm developing this ordering Android app and thought about this problem. Creating an order or fetching user data from the backend is not that important- in case of error, Snackbar, Toast, etc. could be shown to inform user about failed backend call. 
 
But what about Canceling the order? How do I make sure, that no matter what, the POST request to cancel the order, will be sent to the backend?
Thanks in advance :)


Edit:
I'm using Firebase Firestore, and I just need to update one value. But I want to make sure, that no matter what (user turns off the internet, kills the app, etc) Firestore will be updated, when internet will be available.

Comment: If I understand your question, you need response from backend to your request for ensure order was cancelled ?

Comment: If you are calling backend API for cancel order, Just inform to your backend developer if function executed properly then send some response code in response like 200 for success and 400 for some failure.